# gen_tcp based server/client persistent and encrypted(ssl/tls) tcp connection in erlang

Tags: ssl, tcp, erlang, tls1.2, gen-tcp

I have an erlang based messaging application where I am using gen_tcp module to communicate between client and server over tcp. the current implementation is not encrypted and thus secure also. So now i would like to use ssl/tls to secure the transport but unable to find any working example implementation of the same. Can anyone please suggest me how to implement ssl/tls over gen_tcp with a proper example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen Erlang ssl module?

Comment: Yes I have seen but I need a complete gen_tcp based solution over tls. SSL can also work

Comment: https://github.com/processone/fast_tls/blob/master/src/fast_tls.erl